# State won't completely mutate

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I have this login system. When a user logs in, my action sets my state to data (username, email, and userId) I retrieve from firebase authentication and store in a variable called `newUser`, so I can access it and display some of it on the `DOM`.  According to the console log in my `vuex action`, the info is stored in the variable just fine. However, when I console log the data in the file that's supposed to display the data, some of the data does not come through. The `userId` and `email` come through just fine, but the `username` comes through as `undefined`. What would cause this and how can I fix this?

Here's my code from where I'm handling the data:

```js
  state: {
    user: null
  },

  mutations: {
    setUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
  },
```

```js
    userLogin({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("setLoading", true);
      commit("clearError");

      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then(user => {
          commit("setLoading", false);

          const signedInUser = {
            email: payload.email,
            id: user.user.uid,
            username: user.user.displayName
          };

          console.log(signedInUser);
          commit("setUser", signedInUser);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit("setLoading", false);
          commit("setError", err);
        });
    },

  getters: {
    user(state) {
      return state.user;
    }
  }
```

And here's how I'm attempting to access the data to check it and display it on the `DOM`:

```js
  created() {
    console.log(this.$store.getters.user);
  },

  computed: {
    username() {
      return this.$store.getters.user.username;
  },
```

I've attempted to set my user as an empty array, an empty object, and as an object with the pieces of data I want to store explicitly stated, meaning:

```js
user: {
    username: null,
    email: null,
    id: null
}
```

as well, and none of these methods worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Try `Vue.set(state, 'user', payload)`

Comment: Instead of console logs, use the Vue dev tools. You can have live looks into the store and see all actions and mutations in real time, so you can identify exactly what part of the process the issue is happening in.

Comment: you can check the content of user with `console.log( JSON.stringify(user));` this will allow you to see the correct name of your variable and if it is getting to you client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `this.$store.getters.user.username` instead of `this.$store.getters.username`

```
  computed: {
    username() {
      const user = this.$store.getters.user
      if (user) {
         return user.username
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still comes through as undefined. It's weird because if I change username to id or email, those come through just fine.

Comment: I added the guard to it `if (user)`, can you try? Can you show the result of `console.log(signedInUser);`?

Comment: I tried adding the guard like you recommended, but that didn't work either.

Comment: When I console.log signedInUser, I get: `{email: "www@www.com", id: "kJxuEAJmb8atOMRvw2bYF1sXc8t2", username: "www"}`.  But when I console.log this.$store.getters.user, I get: `id: "kJxuEAJmb8atOMRvw2bYF1sXc8t2"
email: "www@www.com"
username: undefined`

Comment: what do you get when you log: `user.username` ?